# Why is viewDidLayoutSubviews called everytime a UITextField is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have a `viewController` that contains a `view` with four `UITextFields` inside of it. What I'm trying to do is animate the view as soon as the ViewController is loaded.

The animation works the way I want when the controller is loaded but for some reason `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called every time I tap any of the `UITextFields` so it keeps animating the view.

Is this normal behavior, is viewDidLayoutSubviews supposed to get called every time a TextField is tapped?

Here is the code I have:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var viewAlertContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        showAlertViewWithAnimation()
    }

    func showAlertViewWithAnimation(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 2, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.viewAlertContainer.frame.origin.y = 150
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: "Is this normal behavior" Pretty obviously yes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will be called anytime *Auto Layout* thinks it has work to do, and that may happen at times you don't expect.  This makes it a poor choice to perform actions that occur once.

Move your animation to an override of `viewDidAppear()`.  That is the first time you know the views are able to be seen, and thus an appropriate place to perform the animation.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    showAlertViewWithAnimation()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the behavior I'm seeing. In my case `viewDidAppear ` doesn't give me the effect I'm looking for since I'm trying to animate the view as soon as the viewController is showing and by doing it there, the view shows and then animates, I'm basically trying to crate the effect in `UIAlertController`. What I ended up doing is animating the top constraint of the view and calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in 'showAlertViewWithAnimation()' but still calling the animation from `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. You answered my question so I'm marking it as the correct one.