# animated expanding of subview by action without constraints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, swift5

I have a UIViewController with a UIScrollView as subview. the scrollview size and origin are computed properties.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        
        let sizeWidth = view.frame.size.width - (view.frame.size.width / 5)
        let sizeHeight = (view.frame.height / 5) * 3
        let originX = (view.width-sizeWidth) / 2
        
        // sizes & positions of container & subviews
        slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: originX,
                                      y: 50,
                                      width: sizeWidth,
                                      height: sizeHeight)
```

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEmKZ.png)

by tapping the sign in or login button, the scrollview should expand animated. but it is the opposite.

```
@objc private func loginButtonTapped() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .allowAnimatedContent) {
            self.slideScrollView.frame.size.height += (self.view.frame.height / 5) * 1
        }
    }
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyZKi.gif)

it should expand, but it sets back to the action height property and expand to regular size,
i hope anyone can tell me why this happens and may have a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called multiple times (In this case twice as I have noticed by adding debug statements) when you start your animation with `UIView.animate(withDuration:` and because you always reset the `slideScrollView.frame` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you see unnecessary side effects.

You can always check this by putting a break point in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` when `loginButtonTapped` gets triggered. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120182/why-is-viewdidlayoutsubviews-called-everytime-a-uitextfield-is-tapped) for similar explaination

If your intention to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is to know when view is properly loaded and its frames are updated properly you can always use

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let sizeWidth = view.frame.size.width - (view.frame.size.width / 5)
        let sizeHeight = (view.frame.height / 5) * 3
        let originX = (view.width-sizeWidth) / 2
        
        // sizes & positions of container & subviews
        slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: originX,
                                      y: 50,
                                      width: sizeWidth,
                                      height: sizeHeight)
    }
```

Now your `loginButtonTapped` should work fine.

As per [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews): `viewDidLayoutSubviews` Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

With that I think my explanation above makes sense, you use `UIView.animate(withDuration:` to modify the frame of `scrollView` so obviously View updates/re-renders the subViews hence `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called when you call `UIView.animate(withDuration:` and because of your frame update code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` you see adverse side effects

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and your solution.
even if I haven't fully understood everything yet, but I'm learning more every day. many thanks again.